# how to add new scope to angularjs reusable templates

Tags: angularjs, scope, reusability

I want to create a reusable template, say contact information with

```
<input> name
<input> telephone
<input> email
```

now, I want to use this partial html in many instances. So I would populate the input for edit in one example or add new Contact in another. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User angularjs directive. That's exactly what its designed to do. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Here is a useful resource to get you started with directives: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/JsFiddle-Examples#version-110